# EF Core 3.1 Not Translating Query Appropriately

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a query that I have written that says it is not translating correctly.
The query is as follows:

```
var query = from a in context.PlaceSyncs
                            join b in (
                                from aa in context.PlaceIdentifiers
                                join bb in context.PlaceSources on aa.PlaceSourceId equals bb.PlaceSourceId
                                select new { Id = aa.PlaceIdentifierId, PlaceKey = aa.PlaceIdentifierKey, PlaceSource = bb.PlaceSourceName }
                            ) on new { a.PlaceKey, PlaceSource = a.PlaceSource.ToLower() } equals new { b.PlaceKey, PlaceSource = b.PlaceSource.ToLower() } into temp
                            from c in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where c == null
                            select new PlaceSync()
                            {
                                PlaceActive = a.PlaceActive,
                                PlaceAddress = a.PlaceAddress,
                                PlaceInformation = a.PlaceInformation,
                                PlaceKey = a.PlaceKey,
                                PlaceName = ((a.PlaceName.Contains("#") == false) ? a.PlaceName : a.PlaceName.Substring(0, a.PlaceName.IndexOf("#"))).TrimEnd().TrimStart(),
                                PlaceSource = a.PlaceSource,
                                PlaceSyncId = a.PlaceSyncId
                            };

var test = query.Count();
```

When I run this in linqpad everything checks out.
When I run this in my application I get the following error:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<PlaceSync>
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<PlaceIdentifier>
            .Join(
                outer: DbSet<PlaceSource>, 
                inner: p0 => p0.PlaceSourceId, 
                outerKeySelector: p1 => p1.PlaceSourceId, 
                innerKeySelector: (p0, p1) => new TransparentIdentifier<PlaceIdentifier, PlaceSource>(
                    Outer = p0, 
                    Inner = p1
                )), 
        inner: p => new { 
            PlaceKey = p.PlaceKey, 
            PlaceSource = p.PlaceSource.ToLower()
         }, 
        outerKeySelector: ti => new { 
            PlaceKey = ti.Outer.PlaceIdentifierKey, 
            PlaceSource = ti.Inner.PlaceSourceName.ToLower()
         }, 
        innerKeySelector: (p, ti) => new TransparentIdentifier<PlaceSync, TransparentIdentifier<PlaceIdentifier, PlaceSource>>(
            Outer = p, 
            Inner = ti
        ))
    .Where(ti0 => new { 
        Id = ti0.Inner.Outer.PlaceIdentifierId, 
        PlaceKey = ti0.Inner.Outer.PlaceIdentifierKey, 
        PlaceSource = ti0.Inner.Inner.PlaceSourceName
     } == null)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I am using .netcore with Micrisoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 3.1.5.
Is there something that is missing in this version of ef that would prevent the query from being translated correctly?

If you can provide an example of the same query that does work in the framework that would be great.

Comment: 100% its the left join.  When I remove it the translation happens perfectly.  I read that there is a breaking change in EF 3.1.5 when navigation properties are missing, but that really doesn;t help me here.  The PlaceSyncs table is completely unrelated to the other tables.  So how exactly do you construct this type of query?

Answer (score 0):

The expression which EG Core 3.x query translator is failing to translate is the anti-join condition

```cs
where c == null
```

In fact such expression has no SQL equivalent - when doing left outer anti-join in SQL one would use some column from the right side which normally is not nullable (usually the PK) for `IS NULL` check.

The same can be used as workaround in the LINQ query, but unlike SQL where NULLs are supported naturally for any expression (even for non nullable columns), the C# expression would require explicit cast to the corresponding nullable type (and ignoring the associate warning).

For instance, if the type of `aa.PlaceIdentifierId` is `int`, then the criteria would be

```cs
where (int?)c.Id == null
```

Comment: This is actually not the case.  When I try to utilize c in any way, I get the same error.  For example if I remove the where clause and I simply put Select new { c } I also receive the same error.  The default value of temp is null.  If you attempt to write the expression in the way you have stated, you will get Id is not a property of null (or something to that effect).  Thanks though...

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19459 (So how do you do it given the limitation?)

Comment: Well, this is is indeed the case with your concrete query. When modified the way I suggested, it produces compiler warning, but translates and executes properly. Of course it's caused by current EF Core limitation/defect, but the workaround works. SO is Q&A site with answers to concrete issues. The above fixes the concrete issue from your question. If you try to utilize `c` variable in a different way, then it is different issue and question. And btw, there is no such thing as 'value of object variable is null' in translated query - this is not Linq to Objects, there are not objects...

Comment: ... involved at all, but pure SQL constructs. As I wrote in the post, these "variables" do not exist, hence cannot be checked for `null`. Usually EF internally translates such checks to nullable PKs as here, just currently fails to do that in some cases like yours. It is simply proved by removing `where` clause from your original query, or using the suggested change.

Comment: In the end I just went with .FromSqlRaw...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just went with .FromSqlRaw...